# angularjs confusion over directives and models

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Am I doing this right ? My scope had some json assigned to it from a controller. I'm iterating thru it using the angularForEach.

I'd like to be able format my td data to be dates. This is a trivial example. Ideally I'd like to use the date filter on my row values but the syntax doesn't seem right. [EDIT] I think I need to use "interpolated values"[/EDIT]

Most of the examples work on curly brackets and seem to be in the actual view. Can someone advise - I'm scared i'm going off on my own path.

```
.directive('betterTable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',        
        link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

            var html = '<table border="1" width="100%">';
            html += '<tr>';
            angular.forEach($scope.result, function (row, index) {
                html += '<td>'; 
                html += row;
                html += '</td>';
            });
            html += '</tr></table>';

        }
   } 
 });
```

Comment: Instead of writing a custom directive, why not write a custom filter? Also, post what's wrong with "the syntax not being right"

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid using the interpolated values (that is, the curly braces, as you mentioned)?

Comment: A couple of things: 1. The link function only runs once, when the directive is set up. You want to use a template with databinding to scope variables. 2. You really should aim to avoid building DOM elements in your directive code. Push this to a template - your directive could do something like prepare/filter the row data, but not build the table/tr/td etc.

Comment: @IshanChatterjee im not trying to avoid interpolated values. In fact I'd prefer it !

Comment: @MikeRobinson so I have my directive rendering ok. However if I look at other examples I've come across we dont seem to use the square brackets. I guess I'm a little unsure how to get what I have to a more appropriate format. In addition using this approach I cant get data binding to work.

Comment: Gotcha, are you trying to make a reusable component or do you see this as more of a one-off? That is, writing a directive is a good approach if you want a generic `betterTable` component that can feed from _any_ data source (given that is has the right data model). I'd suggest pushing this to a view (.HTML) instead and using a `ng-repeat` if you won't reuse the directive elsewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
.directive('betterTable', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<table border="1" width="100%">' +
      '<tr>' +
        '<td ng-repeat="row in result">{{row|date:"short"}}</td>' +
      '</tr>' +
    '</table>',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
      // Nothing to see here...
    }
  } 
});
```

To be honest, you really don't need a directive for this.

If you really want to do the loop in the link function (which I don't advise), this should get you started:

```
.directive('betterTable', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',        
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {

        var html = '<table border="1" width="100%">';
        html += '<tr>';
        angular.forEach($scope.result, function (row, index) {
          html += '<td>';
          html += $compile("{{row|date:'short'}}")($scope);
          html += '</td>';
          // This could also be expressed on one line as:
          // html += $compile("<td>{{row|date:'short'}}</td>")($scope);
        });
        html += '</tr></table>';

    }
  } 
}]);
```

**Edit**: Just to be clear, based on what you have posted I don't see any reason to create a directive.  You could just put this in your view:

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="row in result">{{row|date:"short"}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks @rtcherry ill try this out ! I'll post feedback and upvote/accept accordingly

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to create a directive, what about setting up a partial HTML file?

Directive

```
.directive('betterTable', ['$compile', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateURL: '/root/to/partials/better_table.html',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
        // As you're not restricting the scope, $scope.result will exist here.
    }
  } 
}]);
```

better_table.html (exactly as @rtcherry proposed)

```
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <td ng-repeat="row in result">{{row|date:"short"}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This way, you'll get a better structured code along with a properly updated scope :)

Hope it helps